# How can I keep 'first' and 'second' replacing std::pair with struct?

Tags: c++, struct, std-pair

I have a pair `std::pair<int, long>` and in code at various places use `pr.first`, `pr.second` (also `ppr->first`, `ppr->second`) kind of notations.
Now I want to change the pair to a struct,

```
struct ABC 
{
    int a;
    long b;
};
```

is there a way I can keep these 'first' and 'second' notations in code to access this struct? Maybe creating a function?

Comment: You can just have public members `first` and `second` in your struct?

Comment: But I can't name them first and second, due to code readability issues

Comment: The way that `std::pair` works is it calls its members `first` and `second`; it isn't a special syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Setting aside the reasons for your wanting to do this (which in the absence of any other information seem to be questionable to say the least), the simplest way would be to use

```
struct ABC
{
    int first;
    long second;
};
```

But if you want the members to be called something else *and* you don't want to resort to "getter" functions (which would require parentheses at the calling site), a solution is to use references for the member variables:

```
struct ABC {
    int a;
    long b;

    int& first;
    long& second;

    ABC() : first(a), second(b) {}
};
```

But if you adopt this you need to write the constructors that are part of the "rule of 5" yourself to bind the references correctly, otherwise a seemingly anodyne copy or move will not work.

Although this answer showcases the power of C++, the language is famed for its ability in allowing you to shoot yourself in the foot. Fancy as the solution may well be, the potential for curious bugs to be introduced as your codebase and even the language itself evolve cannot be overstated. As such this ought to be considered to be an antipattern and only used in truly exceptional circumstances.

Comment: You cannot rebind a reference, in general. In particular, if your assignment operator says (e.g.) `a = other.a`, then automatically `first` will also take on the new value. The only time you'd ever need to rebind the reference would be if you tried to `memcpy` the type.

Comment: I think the better way would be to use the first suggested struct and create member functions `a()` and `b()`. That would avoid the references altogether while not breaking existing code.

Comment: @Resurrection: The best thing to do right now is to leave the `std::pair` as it is.

Comment: @Bathsheba Completely agree. :-)

Comment: @Bathseda I never said anything about the constructor body. If you think I did, then you have misread what I was saying. I was wrong about being able to use `= default;` for assignment operators, because that doesn't work if there are reference data members, but there is still no point at which point you can or should rebind any references.

Comment: @Bathsheba To clarify: I never thought you could use `= default` for the constructors, because of the need to initialize the references (in the member initialization list, not the body, which should be empty). I thought (incorrectly) that the assignment operators and (correctly) that the destructor could still be `default`ed. I still think that at no point in the definition of a constructor or an assignment operator should you rebind a reference; you should initialize them in the constructors and ignore them in the assignment operators and destructor.

Comment: I can understrike the statement about _"rule of 5"_. I recently had a bad experience (when I used something like this in my productive code). When I templated the copy constructor, suddenly the default copy constructor was generated implicitly (which I was not aware of) and did bad things. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff: I share the similarly bad memories!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try this:

```
struct ABC 
{
    union {
        int a;
        int first;
    };
    union {
        long b;
        long second;
    };
};
```

This allows you to use `a` and `first` as well as `b` and `second` interchangable.
It might be better though to replace the `first`and `second` usages to avoid confusion.

As pointed out this is [undefined behaviour](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) `12.3 Unions` but will work with MSVC and [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fstrict-aliasing) at least.
thx for the comments

Comment: Accessing union members other than used for initialization is _undefined behavior_.

Comment: Technically this is UB in C++ (although it's defined in C). Although I think most C++ compilers will compile this, particularly ones that purportedly "support" C (e.g. MSVC). If you disclaim adequately I'll upvote as this is an ingenious solution.

Comment: It should be noted that gcc [documents](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fstrict-aliasing) allowing type punning through unions even with `-fstrict-aliasing` on. But it does not explictely document it as a C++ extension...